# Change google-service.json from android studio to firebase_option.dart on flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I have a android studio project that links to firebase with google-service.json file but I am not allowed to access that firebase. I only know google-service.json content.
Now i want to build a flutter project that have firebase_option.dart file. Can i link that google-service.json file to my project? Or what do I need to change for it to work?

**Edit:**
I tried changing the **apiKey**, **appId**, ... from the original file to the flutter file, then copy the google-services.json file and put it in the android folder of the flutter project but it didn't work.
And another problem is that FirebaseOptions **ios** has fields like **iosClientId** and **iosBundleId** which I don't know how to replace it. Can you find a way to help me?

Answer (score 1):

There's no automatic conversion, but you can probably manually convert the values.

What you need on the Flutter side is something like this:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'AI...PM',
    appId: '1:10...7f4',
    messagingSenderId: '10...957',
    projectId: 'yourprojectid',
    storageBucket: 'yourprojectid.appspot.com',
  )
);
```

So start with that code, then find the most likely value in your `google-services.json` and insert that. If you have trouble making a specific key work, post back with what you tried and we can have a look.

---

**Edit** for the new problem with getting iOS-specific values: you can't get the configuration data for an iOS app from the Android-specific `google-services.json` file. You'll need the `GoogleService-info.plist` file for that.

Comment: Thank you very much. But it doesn't resolve my problem. I just edited my post. Can you review it?

Comment: I added a bit about iOS, which isn't gonna work. For the rest of it: instead of describing what you did in words, can you show the resulting code - similar to what I showed in my answer.

Comment: This solved my problem. Some things go wrong because of my fault. I have solved it. Many thanks for your help.